# How do I check & return an error message if an array is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-operator

I am writing a ternary statement that prints out the certification of a movie (IE. PG, R...).

I am trying to return an error message that says "No Certification Available For This Movie" if the length of the array is equal to zero and if it is undefined. I managed to print the error message to the console if the array is equal to zero but I am struggling with printing an error message when it is undefined. I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'release_dates')` in the console.

This is what I have tried:

```
 const movieRating = rating.results;

 //Finding US ratings
 const findUSRating = movieRating.find((item) => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US');

//Filtering US ratings to remove null certifications. 
 const array = findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification);

//Ternary statement & where I am stuck.
console.log(array.length > 0 || array[index] !== undefined ? array[0].certification : `No certification Available For This Movie`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'release_dates')

As per the error, `findUSRating` is not defined. This error is coming as `movieRating` does not contain the object which is having `iso_3166_1` as `US`.

Example **:**

```js
const movieRating = [{
    iso_3166_1: 'Canada'
}, {
    iso_3166_1: 'Australia'
}];

 //Finding US ratings
 const findUSRating = movieRating.find((item) => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US');

//Filtering US ratings to remove null certifications. 
 const array = findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification);
 
 console.log(array);
```

To get rid from this, You can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const movieRating = [{
    iso_3166_1: 'US',
  release_dates: [{
    certification: 'A'
  }]
}, {
    iso_3166_1: 'Australia',
  release_dates: [{
    certification: 'B'
  }]
}];

 //Finding US ratings
 const findUSRating = movieRating?.find((item) => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US');

//Filtering US ratings to remove null certifications. 
 const array = findUSRating?.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification);
 
console.log(array?.length > 0 || array !== undefined ? array[0].certification : `No certification Available For This Movie`);
```

Comment: Thank you this helped and fixed the error I receiving.

Answer (score 1):

the issue come from the line

```
 const array = findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification);
```

findUSRating is undefined and you can't do findUSRating.release_dates

An idea can be to use another ternary to test the variable

```
const array = (findUSRating && findUSRating.release_dates) ? findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification) : [];
```

you will also have the same issue if movieRating is undefined or not an array. you will have to use a similar aproach to prevent error

```
 const findUSRating = (movieRating && movieRating.length) ?movieRating.find((item) => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US') : [];
```

Comment: he will also have an error if `movieRating` is not an array (Type Error: find is not a function ). Could also use same approach as above, `movieRating && movieRating.length > 0 ? movieRating.find((item) => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US') : []`

Comment: thank you i edit my reply with the same aproach for movieRating

Answer (score 0):

You use try catch to catch any errors during runtime.

```js
try {
  const movieRating = rating.results;

   //Finding US ratings
   const findUSRating = movieRating.find((item) => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US');

  //Filtering US ratings to remove null certifications. 
   const array = findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification);

  //Ternary statement & where I am stuck.
  console.log(array.length > 0 || array[index] !== undefined ?    array[0].certification : `No certification Available For This Movie`);
} catch(err) 
{ 
  console.log("Error") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Trevin.
You can change the following code.

```
//Filtering US ratings to remove null certifications. 
const array = findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification);

const array = findUSRating ? findUSRating.release_dates.filter((item) => item.certification) : [];

     or

const array = findUSRating?.release_dates?.filter((item) => item.certification);
```

Hope it helps you.